# Assign the results of a stored procedure into a variable in another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

The title of this question is a bit misleading, but I couldn't summarize this very well.

I have two stored procedures. The first stored procedure (`s_proc1`)  calls a second stored procedure (`s_proc2`). I want to assign the value returned from `s_proc2` to a variable in `s_proc1`. Currently, I'm calling `s_proc2` (inside `s_proc1`) in this manner:

```
EXEC s_proc2 @SiteID, @count = @PagingCount OUTPUT
```

`s_proc2` contains a dynamic query statement (for reasons I will not outline here).

```
CREATE dbo.s_proc2
(
    @siteID int,
    @count int OUTPUT
)

AS

DECLARE @sSQL nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @xCount int

SELECT @sSQL = 'SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Authors'

EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @sSQL, N'@xCount int output', @xCount output
SET @count = @xCount
RETURN @count
```

Will this result in `@PagingCount` having the value of `@count`? I ask because the result I am getting from `s_proc1` is wonky. In fact, what I do get is two results. The first being `@count`, then the result of `s_proc1` (which is incorrect). So, it makes me wonder if `@PagingCount` isn't being set properly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT @sSQL = 'SELECT @xCount = COUNT(ID) FROM Authors' 
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @sSQL, N'@xCount int output', @count = @xCount output
```

Comment: This results in the error
The parameterized query '(@xCount int output)SELECT @xCount = COUNT(i.id)FROM Authors' expects the parameter '@xCount', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 1):

To get the return value you would need to do

```
DECLARE @RC int
EXEC  @RC = s_proc2 @SiteID, @count = @PagingCount OUTPUT
```

Also should your dynamic SQL be

```
'SELECT @xCount = COUNT(ID) FROM Authors'
```

I can't see @xCount being assigned to anywhere.